# laravel 5: HTML tag not working in blade file

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a column in my database with the data from a WYSYWIG form and now I want to display it in my user side. My problem is that it is not working as expected, data is displayed in plain text. Here's the code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="house_rules">@lang('guestform.terms')</label>
    <textarea id="house_rules" name="house_rules" class="form-control" rows="4" disabled> {!! $room['house_rules'] !!}</textarea>
</div>
```

Value for the variable is `<p><u style="font-weight: bold;">aasd </u>asdas&nbsp;</p>`.

By the way, I'm using [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/editors.html) **WYSYWIG** editor.

I even tried parsing it using this `{!! nl2br(e( $room['house_rules'] )) !!}`. Is there something I'm not doing right that I haven't seen?

Comment: What's the value of `$room['house_rules']`?

Comment: @fubar Updated my question.

Comment: @EemJee Can you just try `{{ $room['house_rules'] }}` and check?

Comment: what `WYSYWIG` are you using, put it in question

Comment: @vivek_23 The same result.

Comment: @Aditya I'm also thinking that it might be caused by the 3rd party WYSYWIG editor. I'm using https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/forms/editors.html by the way.